# Where does the big weapon battle trope in chuunibyou come from?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

When Rika and the others released their chuunibyou power, they have a huge weapon and use it like it was nothing. I can't remember any anime where such a big and weird weapon is used like that, that isn't mecha. Is this a reference to anything? or is it original for Chuunibyou?

**Rika fighting against Touka, her sister**
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to ask if it's a parody of anything? Where the big weapon battle trope comes from? What their "powers" are inspired by?

Comment: @Krazer the big weapon thing. Like I said, I can't remember any anime that use such a big and weird weapon like that

Comment: Not everything is a "trope".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chuunibyou's case, the extraordinarily large weapons are used to emphasize the fact that this is in Rikku's imagination, and they are actually fighting with a ladle and an umbrella, which is much less extravagant.

[image]

Having said that, the 'small girl, big weapon' trope is common enough in anime. Take Mami's *Trio Finale* in Puella Magi Madoka Magica for example, or Black Rock Shooter's girls which all have gigantic weapons:

[image] [image]

There are lots of instances of these types of battles, but I wouldn't restrict this trope to anime, with instances of 'Big F**king Guns' going back to games like Doom

[image]

Along with the '100T anvil' trope, These types of tropes are used to emphasize a scene. In this case, making battle scenes more explosive,action-packed and gripping.

[image]